# How to get the 6 most popular drinks from the database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table `CART_ITEMS`, where `drink_id` is the `id` of the drink, and `order_id` is the `id` of the order in which it is located, `count` is the amount of this drink in the order. You need to display the 6 most popular drinks from this table. I don’t understand how this can be implemented ... I got it like this:

```
select drink_id 
  from cart_items
 where drink_id=(select drink_id 
                   from cart_items 
                  group by drink_id 
                  order by count(6) desc 
                  limit 1)
 group by drink_id
 limit 6
```

Accordingly, it doesn't work. Only one of the most popular drinks is displayed.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   drink_id,
   sum(count) as count
FROM cart_items 
GROUP BY drink_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can prefer using instead

```
select drink_id, count(*) as count
  from cart_items 
 group by drink_id 
 order by count desc
 limit 6
```

there's no need to use a subquery.